# MySQL - suggestions to append data to an existing field/record?

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I begin by adding data to table `events`, field `exceptions` like this

```
function events_exceptions($rec_id, $evt_id)
{
//$evt_id = 1;

$this->db->where('record_id', $rec_id);
$this->db->update('events', array('exceptions' => $evt_id));
}
```

This will give me

```
exceptions
1
```

If I run this again with `$evt_id = 2` I'll get

```
exceptions
2
```

and so on.

I want to actually append the new data to that field instead of update, so I would have (note the comma)

```
exceptions
1,2,3  //etc
```

I think this can be done by making a call to DB, reading the content of the row/field, and concatenating via PHP - then updating the record. But I wanted to avoid such overhead.

Is there a way of doing this via MySQL `CONCAT`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$query = "UPDATE table1 SET field1 = CONCAT(ifnull(field1,''),'$extra') WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Comment: thanks - looks like it works, but only if there is data already in that field - if it's empty to begin with, the statement does nothing - how could we solve this issue?

Comment: actually, I now switched to `CONCAT_WS(',',FIELD1,'$extra')` and now it works - thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this piece of code. Seems to be what I was looking for.